# What are the properties of the unsided fold?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, proof-techniques, functional-programming

Foldl and folr are 2 very important functions for FP and Haskell, but I have never heard much about the unsided fold:

```
fold f [a,b,c,d] = (f (f a b) (f c d))
```

That is, a fold that operates on binary associative functions (so the order of application doesn't matter). If I recall correctly, this is very common in databases as it can be parallelized. So, about it, I ask:

1. Is it, like foldr, universal?
2. Like foldr, can you define every important function using it?
3. Is there a fusion rule for it, similar to those for foldr/build and unfoldr/destroy?
4. Why is it barely mentioned?
5. Any consideration worth mentioning?

Comment: Nearly cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986286/is-it-possible-to-implement-foldl-foldr-using-unsided-fold

Comment: Not really, I'm expecting different answers from those different contexts (SO = how to implement foldl with fold, here = general properties of the unsided fold).

Comment: Perhaps you want to cross-post it at cstheory (unless you already have).